# Get facebook user hometown in ios

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am trying to get hometown of users using facebook sdk in ios 
i am using FBFriendPickerViewController and can get information like user id , but id dont know how to get another information like hometown etc...

Answer (score -1):

You have to ask in developers facebook for HOMETOWN data. Assuming you had done this, you have to ask for permissions in your app for retrieve this data;

e.g:

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"basic_info",@"email",@"user_hometown",@"user_location",
                            nil];
```

So, you can use this value like this:

```
_userhometownStr = [user objectForKey:@"hometown"][@"name"];
```

You have to specify the @"name" key, because HOMETOWN is a key-value dict, with ID and NAME.

Regards.